# Object "cast template" getter for a map of Objects?

Tags: java

I wondered if it was possible to create a "templatized" getter, such as :

```
class TestGet
{
    private static Map<String,Object> theMap.....

    public static getObject<T>(String key).....
```

And somewhere in the code, something like :

```
JButton myButton = TestGet.getObject<JButton>("theButton");
```

Beware : this is *just* an "idle" question, I'm trying to avoid "dirty" casts in my code since they make my eyes bleed each time I look at them.

I know there are more elegant ways to do that, but I really would do it with a map of  to avoid linking with other classes.

I tried out some configurations, but nothing seems to fit what I want to do... Is a templating like that just possible ?

Comment: Why do you need that `type parameter`, if you already have a mapping of your key and object in your map?

Comment: @Rohit : I want to "pre-cast" objects before returning them with the getter, since these objects can be eg. JButton, JLabel, String, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write

```
 public static <T> T getObject(String key) {
     return (T) theMap.get(key); // produces a warning.
 }
```

and

```
 JButton myButton = TestGet.<JButton>getObject("theButton");
```

or just

```
 JButton myButton = TestGet.getObject("theButton");
```

---

For a more complicated example ;)

```
class A<T> {
    class B<S> {
        public <U extends S> U tsu() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

List<String> list = new A<Integer>().new B<List>().<List<String>>tsu();
```

Comment: WOW ! TestGet.<JButton>getObject fits me perfectly ! Thanks !

Comment: +1 Didn't knew we can do that way also.. `TestGet.<Type>`. This I have seen for the first time.

Comment: *"more complicated example"* : Amazing example and more than useful, I will use it !

Comment: Still using this very handful tip sometimes, still many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is hide the casts, it's easy as Peter showed. If you want to avoid ClassCastExceptions as well, type erasure dictates you have to pass the class in as a parameter (you can't do `instanceof` on a generic type). It's a bit messy.

```
class TestGet {
    private static final Map<String,Object> theMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getObject(final String key, final Class<T> clazz) {
        final Object o = theMap.get(key);
        return o != null && clazz.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())
               ? (T) o
               : null;
    }
}
```

And then

```
JButton b = TestGet.getObject("theButton", JButton.class);
```

Comment: Okay, nice with the use of Class-type parameter, but I prefer Peter's notation with the < >. Your solution still provides the concept of assignable, which could be useful anyway. +1 for that

Comment: Using TestGet.<JButton>getObject() is only required when the type inferencer can't figure out what type to return (which in Java is far too often). My example was designed to avoid it :)

Comment: I prefer specify it each time, but it's a preference of mine. Thanks for for the isAssignableFrom method, which I was not aware of.